# Identify callback control id

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback

I have a masterpage that contains a user control.  The usercontrol uses callbacks for various operations.  However, every time a callback is issued from the user control it is propagated down to the pages that inherit from the master page.  How do I determine the id of the control that issued the callback so that I can stop these callbacks from destroying the state of the pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string control = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```